# How to make the MS Flow process to sleep after a step has been kick started and then revoke it once the process has been completed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, power-automate

How to make the MS Flow process to sleep after a particular process in a step has been kick started and then a stored proc can revoke it once the process has been completed?

Let me ask my query with an example:
1. An MS Flow has been created and it has a step to queue a build in AZURE dev OPs
2. This queuing step is executed successfully or initiated successfully and it immediately kick starts the next step in the flow

My query is :
Is there any way to make the flow to go into sleep mode temporarily and kick start once the whole build pipeline is executed completely so that i can check the status and then accordingly execute next steps of the flow?

Can this be achieved though SQL Stored Procs which will wake up the flow once the build pipeline execution is completed to its full?

Can this be achieved through any other way?

If yes can you please provide us a step by step detailed guide on how to achieve it as i am new to coding and other things hence would request a detailed guide in order to understand and achieve it?

What we have already tried it put a delay flag with units as Minutes but the case it it times out if i provided like 20 minutes and the flow steps in this case not knowing how to disable the timeout or to overcome the timeout?

What we have already tried it put a delay flag with units as Minutes but the case it it times out if i provided like 20 minutes and the flow steps in this case not knowing how to disable the timeout or to overcome the timeout?

Expected Result: The Flow should stop/sleep for the moment till the queued build execution is completed and re-run once the build is completed then i can check status and do the respective action accordingly.

Actual Result: Not knowing how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should break your current pipeline into two separate flows and give a try to `Request – when an HTTP request is received` trigger - IMHO forcing any action to sleep for fixed amount of time is generally a bad idea (not only because of the performance aspects).

More info on MS site: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/call-flow-restapi/